# Making a UITableView scroll like a UIPickerView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, infinite-loop

I have a UITableView on a UIViewController.
And this table has "say" 5 visible categories to choose from. But in the Array that holds the content i have "say" 10 categories. What i've created now is a normal scrolling table that goes from category 1 on index 0 to category 10 on index 9. 
But what i'd rather have is category 1 also after category 10 and the other way around.

So basically an endless loop of a static Array.

I've tryed this with the scrollViewDidScroll: method, but when i do that it doesn't scroll like you would expect a UITableView to scroll. It RACES to a random spot and moving 1 or two categories is impossible.

Here is a sample of my code. Hope somebody can help.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView == categoryView){
        if (categoryView.contentOffset.y > 0.0) {
            loopcounter++;
            NSLog(@"ScrollView Scrolled DOWN");
            [categorytablecontent insertObject:[categorytablecontent objectAtIndex:0] atIndex:[categorytablecontent count]-1];
            [categorytablecontent removeObjectAtIndex:0];
            [categoryView reloadData];
        }
        if (categoryView.contentOffset.y < 0.0) {
            loopcounter = [categorytablecontent count];
            NSLog(@"ScrollView Scrolled UP");
            [categorytablecontent insertObject:[categorytablecontent objectAtIndex:[categorytablecontent count]-1] atIndex:0];
            [categorytablecontent removeObjectAtIndex:[categorytablecontent count]-1];
            [categoryView reloadData];
        }

        a = categoryView.visibleCells;

        for (UITableViewCell *cell in a){
            NSLog(@"Current Visible cell: %@", cell.textLabel.text);
        }
        NSLog(@"Current offset: %@", categoryView.contentOffset.y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more then one good way to do this. Does your controller implement the *`UITableViewDataSource` Protocol*? If so, the easiest thing would probably be to just return the modulo of your dataset size in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Something like:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    // Use appropriate fields for your categorytablecontent object here...
    cell.textLabel.text = [categorytablecontent objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row % [categorytablecontent count])];

    return cell;
}
```

This should result in a nice smooth infinite scroll that loops through your static (or dynamic) content.